# Include specific file with sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, bower, sprockets

I've installed jasmine via bower:

```
├── angular#1.3.8 (1.3.9-build.3719+sha.a3c3bf3 available)
├─┬ angular-animate#1.3.8 (1.3.9-build.3719+sha.a3c3bf3 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.8 (latest is 1.3.9-build.3719+sha.a3c3bf3)
├─┬ angular-cookies#1.3.8 (1.3.9-build.3719+sha.a3c3bf3 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.8
├─┬ angular-resource#1.3.8 (1.3.9-build.3719+sha.a3c3bf3 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.8
├─┬ angular-route#1.3.8 (1.3.9-build.3719+sha.a3c3bf3 available)
│ └── angular#1.3.8
├─┬ bootstrap#3.3.1
│ └── jquery#2.1.3
├── jasmine#2.1.3
└── require#a45d433fdc
```

However, how do I include it in my project?

According to [their homepage](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine) I need to include:

```
jasmine.js
jasmine-html.js
boot.js
```

However, when I try to include `jasmine.js` with sprockets on my dedicated spec page I get an error:

```
//= require jasmine
```

gives me:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound
couldn't find file 'jasmine'
```

bootstrap, angular and angular's modules all work perfectly with sprockets:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
//= require angular-cookies
//= require bootstrap
```

but not jasmine :(

I don't want to use the gem because I want bower to be incharge of all my clientside libraries.

Is there a way I can hardcode the path with sprockets? I can see the files I need. They're located at:

```
vendor/assets/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
vendor/assets/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js
vendor/assets/bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between bootstrap, angular, angular modules and jasmine is that they all have a *bower.json* while [jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine) is missing it. Bower will be able to resolve a package without a bower.json file, but it has some downsides.
The way sprockets works with bower components is described nicely in this [article](http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2014-12-10-bower-with-rails/). The short version is that when processing a directive like `//= require bootstrap` sprockets will:

- Sprockets will search for *bootstrap* in asset paths.
- If found, it checks whether its a file or a directory. In the rails
  app, bower installed this lib under directory *bootstrap*.
- If directory, it checks if the directory contains *bower.json* file. In
  the rails app, bootstrap folder does have bower.json file.
- It decodes the json file, and parses the main field containing files and
  returns the desired assets.

Now, jasmine has no bower.json file. It does not stop Bower from resolving it,however it means that sprockets will **not** find a main file.
One solution for this would be providing the require [directive](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) a [logical](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#logical-paths) or relative path to the jasmine files you would like to include, for example:

```
//= require jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
```

This is assuming `vendor/assets/bower`_components is part of sprockets [load path](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-load-path).